# Is it possible to know if a user has pulled from a git repository

Tags: git

When someone pulls from a particular repository is this fact stored anywhere in the repo they pulled from?

I have tried looking for commands and log files that would give me this information but so far I haven't came up with anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this information is not stored in the repo that is being pulled from. You could technically fake it by writing your own `git-daemon` that tracked that sort of information, adding an extra process that logs who logged in over `ssh` to pull, but besides that there is nowhere that this information is being stored.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Ha, it is fine, not every question needs to have a positive answer! I will mark this as the accepted answer as soon as I am able.